# PHP - combining php with html to display logged in name

Tags: php, html, session

when the user logs in, their name gets saved into a session variable called `'name'`. All pages should display the user's name if logged in, or a link to log in if the user is not logged in. I have tried the following code in the pages that require this feature, however I am just shown a white screen and I cant figure out where the error may be.

```
<?php if ( isset( $_SESSION['name'] )){ ?> 
<p>Welcome back <?php echo  $_SESSION['name'];?></p> 
<?php} else{?>
<a href="login.php">Login</a> <?php } ?>
```

EDIT: session has been started on the pages

Comment: A white screen is a fatal error. Try adding this to the page to show errors `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: Have you tried adding a session_start() at the beginning of your page?

Comment: 2 hints:  Format it nicely (indenting and all), and look for a new error file in the same directory as this php file

Comment: make sure you have `session_start()` at the top of every page using sessions

Comment: Also, there is a problem with your HTML, although that wouldn't affect the PHP:  `<a href"login.php">` should be `<a href="login.php">`

Comment: @tlenss Yes all the pages hav session_start()

Comment: @Orangepill Yes all the pages hav session_start()

Comment: @Oberon Those lines have been added already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems an erro at Line 3. You have missed spaces after open php tag

```
<?php } else{ ?>
     ^       ^
```

Comment: Sometimes, I use the [alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) in situations where I am weaving PHP and HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

This problem could be caused by not using `session_start()` before accessing `$_SESSION['']`.

Comment: Yes all the pages hav session_start()

Answer (score 0):

Have you added `session_start()` at start of your page?

Comment: Yes all the pages hav session_start()